# How to import QML singleton

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to import my singleton module but keep getting *module "Style" is not installed*

This is my project structure

[image]

Style.qml

```
pragma Singleton
import QtQuick 2.0

QtObject {

    property color subsectionlabelColor: "white"
    property color appSectionTitleColor: "white"
}
```

qmldir

```
singleton Style 1.0 Style.qml
```

Main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

import Style 1.0

Window {
```

I wanted to keep the Style.qml outside of the qrc file so it can be changed more easily.

Please can someone explain what is going on?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't explain what error/unexpected behavior you get.

Comment: My goal is to have a style.qml file that I can use in multiple applications and that can be edited outside of the development environment. Similar to a qss file in qt widgets

Answer (score 2):

Normally, it should work if you **import the directory where your singleton is located**.

In your `Main.qml`, replace `import Style 1.0` with `import "Style"` (or whatever seems to be your relative path from `Main.qml` to the directory containing `Style.qml`. Importing the directory should run the `qmldir` script, which allows for the singleton to kick in.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

import "Style"  // relative path to the directory containing Style.qml

Window {
```

Answer (score 0):

Use addImportPath API of engine to add path of the directory where your qtdir file is located. Refer main.cpp file of the example https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols-flatstyle-example.html

The above mentioned API can be used in your main function as:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
QApplication app(argc, argv);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.addImportPath(":/imports"); /* Insert relative path to your import directory here */
engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/Main.qml")));

return app.exec();
}
```

Import paths needs to be added to solve the error "module not installed" . By default, the import paths would be that of QT source directory